# How do I watch TV channels broadcast using DVB-T2 television standard on my computer and tablet

Tags: windows-7, tv, tablet

I am clueless on what one need to do in order to watch TV channels that is broadcast using DVB-T2 television standard on computer (Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 OS) and tablet (Android tablets).

I know that one connect a DVB-T2 digital set-top box and an Antenna for TV setup but do I do the same on a computer and tablet?

Comment: Start with hardware depending on OS and interface. For example: [dvb-t2 usb](https://www.google.com/search?q=DVB-T2+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=dvb-t2+usb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get a TV Tuner card that support DVB-T2 (e.g. hauppauge WinTV-HVR-5525) and plug into your desktop machine

[image]

```
Supports:
Freesat: High Definition digital satellite DVB-S2.
Freeview HD: digital terrestrial DVB-T2.
Freeview: digital terrestrial DVB-T.
Digital cable TV: DVB-C.
Analogue PAL/SECAM TV.
```

Next, connect a Antenna to the TV Tuner card and install the drivers for the TV Tuner Card.

Lastly, use the software that come with the TV Tuner card to watch your TV channels that is broadcast using the DVB-T2 television standard.